# Custom rails environment log getting written to nginx error.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, nginx, passenger

I have a custom environment for my app called staging.  For some reason, no staging.log file ever gets created, and all of the stuff that I would assume to be written there is instead showing up in the nginx error.log file.  Is there a configuration option that I'm missing?

Comment: possibly; also check permissions on the dir where the log would normally be created, it should be writeable by the user that rails is running as.

Comment: I checked the permissions, and they look fine.  The new_relic.log and the delayed_job.log file in the same folder have the same permissions. :(

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I just ran into the same issue and wanted to share what fixed it for me in case it helps anyone else who runs into this.

In my case, I was using the **rails_12factor** gem (because I had my app deployed on Heroku at one point), which causes all logging to go to stdout. This caused it all to get dumped into the nginx_error.log. I was able to completely remove the gem to fix it, since I don't use Heroku for the app any more, but if you need to support Heroku deployment you could add some sort of configuration so that rails_12factor only gets required in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like

```
c = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("log/staging.log")
c.auto_flushing = true
config.logger = c
```

to your `config/environments/staging.rb`
Also you maybe should play with auto_flushing option, rails guide about [configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html), says it's turned off in production env, I don't know why. See BufferedLogger docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BufferedLogger.html).
It doesn't look to me like perfect solution, but looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

for logging in nginx you have:

- the `error_log` directive, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log
- the `acces_log` directive, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log

there's one gotcha with the `error_log`:

if you have it set to `debug`, while your nginx is not compiled using the `--with-debug` flag, it will fallthrough to the default error.log location.

to check if your the flags your nginx was compiled with use the `nginx -V` command